# OleDb No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

i've been trying to send a select query to my excel file with OleDb but i am getting an exception that says 'No value given for one or more required parameters'

Here is my code:

```
using (var scon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\""))
        {
            scon.Open();
            var param = obj.data.Replace("*", "");
            var scom = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [AAA$] WHERE [HDRNAME] <> '"+param+"'", scon);
            var sqr = scom.ExecuteReader();
            var newobj = new dboject();
            while (sqr.Read())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5);
                newobj.data = sqr[2].ToString();
                break;
            }
            return newobj;
        }
    }
```

i get the exception on this line :

```
var sqr = scom.ExecuteReader();
```

i've also tried without header by using excel cell names but this time it just ignores where clause and gets everything.

Code:

```
using (var scon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;\""))
        {
            scon.Open();
            var param = obj.data.Replace("*", "");
            var scom = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [AAA$] WHERE [F5] <> '"+param+"'", scon);
            var sqr = scom.ExecuteReader();
            var newobj = new dboject();
            while (sqr.Read())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5);
                newobj.data = sqr[2].ToString();
            }
            return newobj;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `HDRNAME` and value of `param`?

Comment: @SonerGönül they are both strings and value of param is like this 'SCD-01/55'.

Comment: Is this command work in your excel file?